# transaction in Algorand v2 using flask

Tags: python, flask, algorand

This is the error I got when I try to make a transfer:

```
algosdk.error.AlgodHTTPError: TransactionPool.Remember: transaction WA5KXR7UGIA4BZTKCK5X5MWQNZOZRB6726ISQVLVE5FQHW2BAHHQ: overspend (account KD3DOFNWGWBFVZUNCS5JYIUOSJMC6VECXKTY6WXMQQBPEPD4ZXQNH76GGY, data {_struct:{} Status:Offline MicroAlgos:{Raw:0} RewardsBase:0 RewardedMicroAlgos:{Raw:0} VoteID:[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] SelectionID:[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] VoteFirstValid:0 VoteLastValid:0 VoteKeyDilution:0 AssetParams:map[] Assets:map[] AuthAddr:AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAY5HFKQ AppLocalStates:map[] AppParams:map[] TotalAppSchema:{_struct:{} NumUint:0 NumByteSlice:0} TotalExtraAppPages:0}, tried to spend {1000})
```

This error shows i tried to spend {1000} which is not the amount but a fee.

```
params = algod_client.suggested_params()
    form = TransferForm(request.form)
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():
        sender = form.sender.data
        receiver = form.receiver.data
        #amount = int(form.amount.data)

    # Debugging
        #params = algod_client.suggested_params()
        # comment out the next two (2) lines to use suggested fees
        params.flat_fee = True
        params.fee = 1000
        #receiver = "HZ57J3K46JIJXILONBBZOHX6BKPXEM2VVXNRFSUED6DKFD5ZD24PMJ3MVA"
        note = "Hello World".encode()
        amount = 10000000
        unsigned_txn = PaymentTxn(sender, params, receiver, amount, None, note)
        

        #return unsigned_txn
    # End

        
        try:
            signed_txn = unsigned_txn.sign(mnemonic.to_private_key(session['passphrase']))
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Any transaction on Algorand requires payment of a fee (at least 0.001 Algo = 1,000 microAlgos).

The account you are using (`KD3DOFNWGWBFVZUNCS5JYIUOSJMC6VECXKTY6WXMQQBPEPD4ZXQNH76GGY`) is empty and cannot pay the fee.

You need to add Algos to the account:

- on MainNet, you need to buy Algos, e.g., on an exchange
- on TestNet, you need to get fake/TestNet Algos from the TestNet dispenser https://bank.testnet.algorand.network/
- on a private network, you need to manually send Algos from a genesis account

If you have Algos in your accounts (and see them on a block explorer such as algoexplorer.io), then you need to check that the node you are connected to is:

1. connected to the right network (MainNet, TestNet, private)
2. is synced to the network (`goal node status` should show `Sync time: 0.0` and the last round should match the one on a block explorer such as algoexplorer.io)

PS: I recommend asking questions related to Algorand directly on https://forum.algorand.org